# How to get the duration of a build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

In the jenkins dashboard there is a column for the duration of the last build.

How do i get the duration of a build which is not the last build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go the the job build history and its in the top right corner

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you click on the **trend** link on the top right corner of the 'Build History' box if will show you the duration of all jobs, this is handy to see how the current running job compares to previous jobs execution time.